# AGS10 Soap Geometry/Project function vanishes

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, c#

So I am doing a pretty simple process that looks a lot like right out of the SOAP API/SDK for AGS10.

My webservices takes a Lat/Lon coord from a mobile app, I reproject it to Web-Mercator to identify against my mapservice data and return a result. Pretty simple, but for some reason that I am not seeing any place, the project method is returning blank, no exception raised, no errors on the server/service side.

```
            SpatialReference inputSpatialReference = new GeographicCoordinateSystem();
            inputSpatialReference.WKID = 4326; //WGS 84
            inputSpatialReference.WKIDSpecified = true;

            PointN llPnt = new PointN { X = lon, Y = lat, Z = 0 };
            llPnt.SpatialReference = inputSpatialReference;

            SpatialReference outputSpatialReference = new ProjectedCoordinateSystem();
            outputSpatialReference.WKID = 3857; //Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere)
            outputSpatialReference.WKIDSpecified = true;

            Geometry[] inputGeometry = new Geometry[] { llPnt };

            bool transformForward = false;

            GeoTransformation transformation = new GeoTransformation();
            // NAD1983_To_WGS1984_1
            transformation.WKID = 108100;
            transformation.WKIDSpecified = true;

            EnvelopeN extent = null;

            Geometry[] outputGeometry = geometryService.Project(inputSpatialReference, outputSpatialReference,
                                                                transformForward, transformation, extent,
                                                                inputGeometry);

            PointN wmPnt = outputGeometry[0] as PointN;
```

Now; when my defining my points works great; I am able to see the point, my X, Y and Z values as well as my existing coordinate system look great. So I define where my coordinates are going, to, define my transformation since I need to get from Lat/Lon to WebMercator and then after that, fire the GeometryService.Project call.

Now when I look at the output in the debugger of the outputGeometr the point is blank; not even the existing coordinates the new point is null.

So I look to the server, to see what it says; no errors listed, so I am very puzzled.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting the transformation WKID 108100 from? Looking at the [enum list](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esrigeometry/esriSRGeoTransformationType.htm) linked from the [SOAP documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/soap/index.htm) I see `esriSRGeoTransformation_NAD1983_To_WGS1984_1 = 1188`

---

**UPDATE**

Creating SOAP proxies off an ArcGIS Server 10.0 SP2 GeometryService endpoint and literally copy-pasting your code and touching it up to run off my new service reference, I get a fine good answer back from the server. Have you looked at the actual exchange with the server in a tool like Fiddler?

Comment: I was trying to different permutations; and didn't think NAD to WGS would hit my mark since I was jumping around a bit. Yet still looking at that as my transformation WKID still leaves the project returning with 'NaN' as all values..

Comment: Kind of puzzled; but going to take the short way out; just setup a copy of the layer I need in WGS. Easy to do since the services are all scripted to replicate. Just sort of spinning my wheels on this one. Thanks for the feedback Philip.